# Where can I find open source graphics for print layouts?

Tags: adobe-indesign, book, layout

I'm looking for some assets to decorate an Art Book I'm working on. Simple textures, board trims, etc are what I'm after.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some assets to be found here and also browse the other categories on the left: http://www.briarpress.org/cuts/browse?t=17